# c++: Multiple definitions when overriding operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am working on implementing a class for a rational number, which of course involves overriding common operators like '==' and '!='.  I'm pretty sure there is a stupid mistake somewhere that I am missing, don't hesitate to ask for any file that I haven't provided.  Thanks!

rational.hpp:

```
#ifndef RATIONAL_HPP
#define RATIONAL_HPP

#include "test.hpp"

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

// Mathematical helper functions.
//
// NOTE: These are defined in rational.cpp.
int gcd(int, int);
int lcm(int, int);


// Represents a rational number. The rational numbers are the set of
// numbers that can be represented as the quotient of two integers.
struct Rational
{
  // TODO: Define the following:
  // 1. A default constructor
    int n;
    int d;
    Rational()
    :n(0), d(1) {}

  // 2. A constructor that takes an integer value
    Rational(int num)
    :n(num), d(1){}
  // 3. A constructor that takes a pair of values
    Rational(int numer, int denom)
    :n(numer), d(denom) {
    assert( d != 0);
        int gcdnum;
        if ((numer % denom) != 0){
            //do nothing
        }else{
            gcdnum = gcd(numer, denom);
            numer /= gcdnum;
            denom /= gcdnum;
            Rational(numer, denom);
        }
    }
  // Returns the numerator.
  int num() const { 
    return n;
}

  // Returns the denominator
  int den() const { 
    return d;
 }

};


bool operator==(Rational a, Rational b){
        return (a.n == b.n && a.d == b.d);
}
bool operator!=(Rational a, Rational b){
        return (a.n != b.n && a.d != b.d);
}
bool operator < (Rational a, Rational b){
        int lcdNum = lcm(a.d, b.d);
        int newAN, newBN; //allows for comparisons without altering actuial value
        newAN = a.n * lcdNum;
        newBN = b.n * lcdNum;
        return newAN < newBN;
}
bool operator > (Rational a, Rational b){
        int lcdNum = lcm(a.d, b.d);
        int newAN, newBN; //allows for comparisons without altering actuial value
        newAN = a.n * lcdNum;
        newBN = b.n * lcdNum;
        return newAN > newBN;
}
bool operator <= (Rational a, Rational b){
        int lcdNum = lcm(a.d, b.d);
        int newAN, newBN; //allows for comparisons without altering actuial value
        newAN = a.n * lcdNum;
        newBN = b.n * lcdNum;
        return newAN <=  newBN;
}

bool operator >= (Rational a, Rational b){
        int lcdNum = lcm(a.d, b.d);
        int newAN, newBN; //allows for comparisons without altering actuial value
        newAN = a.n * lcdNum;
        newBN = b.n * lcdNum;
        return newAN >= newBN;
}

// 3. The standard arithmetic operators
//    - r1 + r2
//    - r1 - r2
//    - r1 * r2
//    - r1 / r2
//    - r1 / r2
Rational operator + (Rational a, Rational b){
    int lcdNum = lcm(a.d, b.d);
    int newAN, newBN; //allows for comparisons without altering actuial value
    newAN = a.n * lcdNum;
    newBN = b.n * lcdNum;
    Rational c((newAN + newBN), (a.d * lcdNum));
    return c;
}
Rational operator - (Rational a, Rational b){
    int lcdNum = lcm(a.d, b.d);
    int newAN, newBN; //allows for comparisons without altering actuial value
    newAN = a.n * lcdNum;
    newBN = b.n * lcdNum;
    Rational c((newAN + newBN), (a.d * lcdNum));
    return c;
}
Rational operator * (Rational a, Rational b){
    Rational c((a.n * b.n), (a.d * b.d));
    return c;
}
Rational operator / (Rational a, Rational b){
    Rational c((a.n * b.d), (a.d * b.n)); //multiplies by the reciprocal
    return c;
}


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Rational);
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Rational&);


#endif
```

rational.cpp:

```
//
// rational.hpp: Definition of rational class and its interace.

#include "rational.hpp"

#include <iostream>


// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// Helper functions

// Compute the GCD of two integer values using Euclid's algorithm.
int
gcd(int a, int b)
{
  while (b != 0) {
    int t = b;
    b = a % b;
    a = t;
  }
  return a;
}


// Compute the LCM of two integer values.
int
lcm(int a, int b)
{
  return (std::abs(a) / gcd(a, b)) * std::abs(b);
}


// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// Rational implementation


// TODO: Make this print integers when the denominator is 1.
 std::ostream&
 operator<<(std::ostream& os, Rational r)
{
  if(r.den() == 1){
   return os << r.num();
}else{
  return os << r.num() << '/' << r.den();
}
}


// TODO: Make this read integer values if no '/' is given as a separator.
// You may assume that there is no space between the numerator and the
// slash. Hint, find and read the reference documentation for istream::peek().
 std::istream&
 operator>>(std::istream& is, Rational& r)
{
  int p, q;
  char c;
  is >> p;
  c = is.peek();
  if (c == '/'){
    is >> c >> q;
    if (!is)
      return is;

     // Require that the divider to be a '/'.
    if (c != '/') {
      is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
      return is;
    }

    // Make sure that we didn't read p/0.
    if (q == 0) {
      is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
      return is;
    }

    r = Rational(p, q);
    return is;
  }else{
    is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
}
}
```

rc.cpp:

```
// main.cpp: rational number test suite

#include "rational.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <unistd.h>


int
main()
{
  // Determine if input is coming from a terminal.
  bool term = isatty(0);

  // This will continue reading until it reaches the end-of-input.
  // If you are using this interactivly, type crtl-d to send the
  // end of input character to the terminal.
  while (std::cin) {
    Rational r1;
    Rational r2;
    std::string op;

    if (term)
      std::cout << "> ";

    std::cin >> r1 >> op >> r2;
    if (!std::cin)
      break;

    // FIXME: Add all of the other overlaoded operators by adding
    // cases for each of them.
    if (op == "==") 


     std::cout << std::boolalpha << (r1 == r2) << '\n';
    else if (op == "!=")
     std::cout << std::boolalpha << (r1 != r2) << '\n';
    else if (op == "<")
     std::cout << std::boolalpha << (r1 < r2) << '\n';
    else if (op == ">")
     std::cout << std::boolalpha << (r1 > r2) << '\n';
    else if (op == "<=")
     std::cout << std::boolalpha << (r1 <= r2) << '\n';
    else if (op == ">=")
     std::cout << std::boolalpha << (r1 >= r2) << '\n';
    else if (op == "+")
     std::cout << (r1 + r2) << '\n';
    else if (op == "-")
     std::cout << (r1 - r2) << '\n';
    else if (op == "*")
     std::cout << (r1 * r2) << '\n';
    else if (op == "/")
     std::cout << (r1 / r2) << '\n';
    else
     std::cerr << "invalid operator: " << op << '\n';

  }

  // If we got to the end of the file without fatal errors,
  // return success.
  if (std::cin.eof())
    return 0;

  // Otherwise, diagnose errors in input and exit with an error
  // code.
  if (std::cin.fail()) {
    std::cerr << "input error\n";
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Can you be more specific about the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every translation unit that `#include`s your `rational.hpp` is going to get the definition of the comparison operator functions, which will certainly result in duplicate definitions at link time.

Try sticking an "inline" keyword in front of them.

Comment: I was reading about include guards and it said they are used to prevent multiple definitions. Now, the OP has an include guard in his code yet this is somehow still a problem, why?

Comment: @templateboy Include guards defend against *multiple inclusion* within a *single* translation unit. This answer talks about *multiple definition* across *multiple* translation units.

Answer (score 3):

You're defining functions inside `rational.hpp`, that means every translation unit include `rational.hpp` will include the definitions, and cause a duplicate definition error.

You should sperate the declaration and definition into header file and implementation file. Such as,

rational.hpp:

```
bool operator==(Rational a, Rational b);
bool operator!=(Rational a, Rational b);
...
```

rational.cpp:

```
bool operator==(Rational a, Rational b){
        return (a.n == b.n && a.d == b.d);
}
bool operator!=(Rational a, Rational b){
        return (a.n != b.n && a.d != b.d);
}
...
```

BTW: The logic in `operator!=` seems to be wrong, I suppose it might be `return (a.n != b.n || a.d != b.d);`. Anyway, as @NickyC suggested, it's better to implement it as `return !(a == b);` to avoid repetiton.

Comment: I think `(a.n != b.n && a.d != b.d)` is a logic (maths) error. It makes `1/4` and `2/4` "not not equal". We should mind the De Morgan's Law. I prefer implementing `!=` in terms of `==`.

Comment: I was reading about include guards and it said they are used to prevent multiple definitions. Now, the OP has an include guard in his code yet this is somehow still a problem, why?

Comment: @templateboy Including guards is used for prevent multiple definition error in **one** translation unit, which will happen at compile time. The OP's issue is a link error, including guards couldn't prevent that across translation units.

Comment: @templateboy 2 cpp files both including the same header once. Both cpp files generate object files that contain the same functions defined in the header. Linker tries to assemble the program and finds the same functions defined twice. Which does it use? Neither. It requests that the programmer clean up and clarify.

Comment: @user458 and (at)songyuanyao Thank you.